# Jquery post form not working on Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

Form `.post()` not working on firefox, but in Chrome it's ok. I had this code:

```
function saveD() {     
    frm = $('#saveDetailsForm');
    $.post(frm.attr('action'), frm.serialize(), function(data) {
        //do smth....
    });

    return false;
}
```

I'm trying to post all inputs of the form, this way doesn't give me any result in Firefox, but it works on Chrome. Anybody can help, please?

Comment: Have you tried debugging with Firebug or Firefox's built-in tools?

Comment: Yes i tried. It doesn't display any error. Post data are empty.

Comment: Have you tried `$.ajax`? It's a bit more explicit than `$.post` but may show you what's going on.

Comment: I solved it by posting form inputs one by one. I removed `frm.serialize()`. Replaced with: `{sID: $("[name=sID]").val(),.....}`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by posting form inputs one by one. I removed `frm.serialize()`. Replaced with: `{sID: $("[name=sID]").val(),.....}`.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst you've got it working, it's not really a great solution. It's pretty unclean, and the moment you change your form, it breaks. I'd suggest getting to the bottom of the underlying problem.

Maybe try using $.ajax as @CameronTinker suggested? Try something like :

```
$.ajax({
  url: frm.attr("action"),
  type: "POST",
  data: frm.serialize(),
  success: function() {
    ... do something ...
  }
});
```